# conda cache for docker

Tags: docker, conda

This is a very similar question to: [Docker build: use http cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53740286/docker-build-use-http-cache)

I would like to set up a docker container with a custom conda environment.
The corresponding dockerfile is:

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

RUN conda update conda
RUN conda env create -f environment.yml
RUN echo "source activate my_env" > ~/.bashrc
ENV PATH /opt/conda/envs/env/bin:$PATH
```

My environment is rather large, a minimal version could look like this:

```
name: my_env
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.6.8=h0371630_0
prefix: /opt/conda
```

Every time that I make changes to the dependencies, I have to rebuild the image. And that means re-downloading all the packages.
Is it possible to set up a cache somehow?
Interfacing the containerized conda with a cache outside the container probably breaks the idea of containering it in the first place.
But maybe this is still possible somehow ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This](https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/afwglg/cache_docker_downloads/ee2d07z) is a very indirect answer to the question, but it works like a charm for me.

Out of the many dependencies, there is a large subset which never changes. I always need python 3.6, numpy, pandas, torch, ...

So, instead of caching conda, you can cache docker and reuse a base image with those dependencies already installed:

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3

WORKDIR /app
COPY environment.yml /app

# install package dependencies
RUN conda update conda
RUN conda env create -f environment.yml
RUN echo "source activate api_neural" > ~/.bashrc
ENV PATH /opt/conda/envs/env/bin:$PATH
```

Then you can add additional config on top of this, in a second dockerfile:

```
FROM base_deps

# add additional things on top, here I'm running some python in the conda env
RUN /bin/bash -c 'echo $(which python);\
source activate api_neural;\
python -c "import nltk; nltk.download(\"wordnet\"); nltk.download(\"words\")";\
python -m spacy download en;\
python -c "from fastai import untar_data, URLs; model_path = untar_data(URLs.WT103, data=False)"'
```

Comment: could you clarify where base_deps is defined. Is this just a file called "base_deps" or is it defined in some other manner?

Comment: its the image created by that first snippet

Answer (score 10):

With Docker [Buildkit](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/) there is now a feature for just this, called cache mounts. For the precise Syntax see [here](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/master/frontend/dockerfile/docs/syntax.md#run---mounttypecache). To use this feature, change:

```
RUN conda env create -f environment.yml
```

to

```
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/opt/conda/pkgs conda env create -f environment.yml
```

and make sure that Buildkit is enable (eg via `export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1`). The cache will persist between runs and will be shared between concurrent builds.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to bind your dev directory to the one on the docker container. Your changes will automatically update the container in this case. You only have to rebuild the image if you actually update any python packages.

```sh
docker run -it --mount "type=bind,source=/local/path,target=/container/path" container_name bash
```

E.g. I for debugging in VS Code my task looks like this:

```json
{
    "type": "docker-run",
    "label": "docker-run: debug",
    // No need to build as we bind our dev environment 
    // "dependsOn": ["docker-build"],
    "python": {
        "file": "example.py"
    },
    "dockerRun": {
        "image": "image_name",
        "containerName": "container_name",
        // first part allows the container to use the hosts display
        // second part binds our local dev folder to the container
        "customOptions":
            "--rm -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix --mount \"type=bind,source=/local/path,target=/container/path\""
    }
},
```